# How to pass the data from view controller to the table view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to pass data from view controller to table view controller? and also how to store the selected data to the table view controller? but The output shows multiple row, how to make it based on the user click at the bag? and how to pass the data inside it?

[image: Here My Interface]

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xka3D.png) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xka3D.png)

Here my Item Detail View Controller

```
import UIKit


class ItemDetailViewController: UIViewController {

     var items = [item]()

    var name : String = ""
    var price : String = ""
    var imagee : String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var labelname: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelprice: UILabel!

//here the button to add to the table view

    @IBAction func addtobag(_ sender: Any) {

        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BagViewController") as? BagViewController
        viewController?.name = self.name
        viewController?.imagee = self.imagee
        viewController?.price = self.price

        viewController?.items = self.items
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        labelname.text = name
        labelprice.text = price
        image.image = UIImage(named: imagee)

    }

}
```

And here my Bag View Controller

```
import UIKit

class BagViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var totalprice: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var items = [item]()

    var name : String = ""
    var price : String = ""
    var imagee : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return name.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ShoppingTableViewCell

        return cell
    }        
}
```

and here my Shopping Table View

```
import UIKit

class ShoppingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    

    @IBOutlet weak var dfs: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelname: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelprice: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var stepperlabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        stepperlabel.text = String(Int(sender.value))
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have a déjà-vue. `name` cannot be the data source array in `BagViewController`. What are an array `items` **and** the three properties `name`, `price` and `image` for in both `Detail` and `Bag` controller? And why don't you use the segue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is kind of bad, you're instantiating a VC in code but you have a segue, I recommend you pass data through the prepare function:

```
// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    if let vc = segue.destination as? BagViewController {
        vc.name = self.name
        vc.imagee = self.imagee
        vc.price = self.price
        vc.items = self.items
    }

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

And in your *addtobag* IBAction you just will call the segue, I recommend you to use a String based segue extension [String+PerformSegue.swift](https://gist.github.com/JCTec/34bdeb354bf7aff1d26eca7957c6ea18) it lets you easily perform segue in a given ViewController like this:

```
@IBAction func addtobag(_ sender: Any) {
    "nameOfTheSegue".performSegue(on: self)
    // If you don't want to use String+PerformSegue.swift uncomment      
    // the next line and comment the last one.
    // self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nameOfTheSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: where should I input the override func prepare(for segue: ..)? and in the @IBAction show Value of type 'String' has no member 'performSegue', can u help me?

Comment: Hello! In my question I put that you needed this gist https://gist.github.com/JCTec/34bdeb354bf7aff1d26eca7957c6ea18 that is called String+PerformSegue.swift but! you can change the code in add to bag to this self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nameOfTheSegue", sender: nil)

Comment: I edit my answer to include a version without the Extension, if you don't know what extensions are I recommend you to look this page about it https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html